# If $f:\mathbb R \to\mathbb{R}^3$ is class $C^1$ and regular at t then $f$ has a strong tangent at $t$

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-line

I'm reading Elements of Geometry for Manfredo Do Carmo and I'm stucked in this problem.
The book define the strong tangent: $f$ has a strong tangent at $t$ if the line determined by $f(t+h), f(t-k)$ has a limit position when $h,k\to 0$

I'm tried to show that $f$ has a unique tangent at $t$, in this case the strong tangent is the same as the weak tangent.

I think if f has two tangents then the continuity of f′ is broken...but I don't know how show that...

If we consider the curve $f(t)=(t^3,t^2)$, $f$ doesn't have strong tangent at $t=0$ because we can aproach the tangent $L=\{(\alpha,0):\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$ by the lines determined by the points $(h^3,h^2),(-h^3,h^2)$

But that lines aren't tangent lines and the line $L$ is impossible to aproach by tangent lines.

Then the regularity is crucial, I don't understand how it that works in the general case.

Comment: So what have you tried and what is your difficulty? It's impossible to guess what problem you might be having.

Comment: I'm tried to show that $f$ has a unique tangent at $t$, in this case the strong tangent is the same as the weak tangent.

Comment: I think if $f$ has two tangents then the continuity of $f'$ is broken...but I don't know how show that...

Comment: OK, so have you tried using a Taylor expansion centered at $t$? Yes, regularity gives you the candidate for the strong tangent line.

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried using the Taylot theorem and I have:
$\frac{f(t+h)-f(t-k)}{h+k}=f'(t)+\frac{h}{h+k}\phi(t,h)+\frac{k}{h+k}\phi(t,-k)$

Comment: I don't know how I can prove: $\frac{h}{h+k}\phi(t,h)\to0$ if $h,k\to0$

Comment: First, I assume that $h,k>0$, although you've never made this explicit. Second, note then that $\left|\frac h{h+k}\right|\le 1$ and that $\phi(t,h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$.